# Multiline secondary text for list react component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a second line of the secondary text of a list react [material ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/#folder-list) component.

How can I modify it? See live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xj05rl6k6z).

```
<ListItemText primary="Photos" secondary="first row" secondary="second row"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I edited on file demo.js of (demo link)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import ImageIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Image";
import WorkIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Work";
import BeachAccessIcon from "@material-ui/icons/BeachAccess";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
});

function FolderList(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <Avatar>
            <ImageIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <ListItemText
            primary="Photos"
            secondary={
              <div>
                <div>line 1</div>
                <div>line 2</div>
              </div>
            }
          />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <Avatar>
            <WorkIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <ListItemText primary="Work" secondary="Jan 7, 2014" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <Avatar>
            <BeachAccessIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <ListItemText primary="Vacation" secondary="July 20, 2014" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}

FolderList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(FolderList);
```

secondary props is node type, You can pass props as:

```
secondary={         
<div>
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
</div>
}
```